# How do I backup or copy a table prior to droptable or createtable in code migration?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I had just removed all records in __MigrationHistory, removed all configuration and migration files, so what I have now is to "reset" migration. But when I issued Add-Migration Initial again, it generates all droptables and createtables, and definitely when I run the updata-database, all records will be gone!

Is there a mechanism I can copy or backup the contents of a table prior to issuing the DropTable("MyTable") then CreateTable(...) in code migration?

Or is there another way around it without data loss?

Thanks,

Comment: And if possible to backup or copy a table, I plan to bring back the data in seed()

Comment: can you create a copy with `select * into myTable_Copy From MyTable_Orig`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you set your current schema as a starting point by running

```
Add-Migration InitialCreate –IgnoreChanges
```

This will create an empty migration and won't wipe your tables. Now you can move forward with new changes and generate migrations as needed.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn579398.aspx#option1